# How do I access my viewmodel variables in my knockout component template?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-components, knockout-templating

I am trying to create a list of instruction steps using Knockout components/templates.

The UL is the going to contain a list of steps (using a knockout-registered custom element **sidebar-step**) which is just a template of `<li></li>`. I have another value `this.testVar` part of my model that could contain an attribute of `<li>` such as the *class*, or maybe a *"data-customAttribute"*.

My question is, **how do I include my `testVar` value into the template?** I want it so that it might output a line like:

`<sidebar-step class=*testVar* params="vm: sidebarStepModel">Message 1</sidebar-step>`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/1/

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <sidebar-step params="vm: sidebarStepModel"></sidebar-step>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
ko.components.register("sidebar-step", {
    viewModel: function (params) {
        this.vm = params.vm;
    },

    template: "<li data-bind=\'text: vm.message\'></li>"
});

var SidebarStepModel = function () {
    this.message = ko.observable("step description");
    this.testVar = ko.observable("some value");
};

var ViewModel = function () {
    this.sidebarStepModel = new SidebarStepModel();
    this.sidebarStepModel.message("Message 1");
    this.sidebarStepModel.testVar("69");


};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Pass it as another parameter?
https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/2/

Comment: @RoyJ maybe, but what if I wanted to set like the style class of the element to whatever is in `testVar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data-bind` on the custom tag. To set class,

```
<sidebar-step data-bind="css:sidebarStepModel.testVar" params="vm: sidebarStepModel"></sidebar-step>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uu4hzc41/3/

Comment: sweet, didn't know you could do it that way, ty